# Multiple image display in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to display multiple images in a JSP. Tui images are stored in local disk. Using servlet I'm generating the absolute addresses of the images, stored in a list, sending the list to JSP using `request.setAttribute()`, method. In JSP after receiving the list I use the following code

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${images}" >
    <img src="${i}" ><br/>
</c:forEach >
```

In the output I'm not getting the images.. But the generated HTML is correct, and running the generated HTML as a normal HTML file I'm getting the images, but not in JSP. Can anyone please specify the error ?

Comment: Could you show the generated html ? And is it correctly interpreted by the browser as HTML ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>JSP Page</title> </head> <body> <img src='C:\test\IMG_20140913_174300.jpg'/><br> <img src='C:\test\pic1.jpg'/><br> <img src='C:\test\pic2.jpg'/><br> <img src='C:\test\pic3.jpg'/><br> <img src='C:\test\pic4.jpg'/><br> <img src='C:\test\pic5.jpg'/><br> <img src='C:\test\ThumperDC.jpg'/><br> </body> </html>

Comment: This is the generated html..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your browser console? You had mentioned that you use the absolute path to your images. if you are using a browser like Chrome, it will block displaying those images as it treat those absolute paths like a security threat.even it is in local drive, you will not be able to load it.

my suggestion is to:

1. deploy your images folder inside webapps folder of Apache tomcat.
   Or else you can deploy it as a different folder inside the same server you deploy your current      application war.
2. access your images as a URL. (ex: http:/localhost:9090/myApp/dir1/hello.jpg) not like the absolute path.

this should solve your problem. 
Note: sometimes you may get "access-origin" or cross-domain file loading issue.
then you can use "cors.jar" or "jsonp callback" to avoid that issue.

Hope that will help you!

Comment: Happy it solves your problem...please up vote it if you really appreciate it. Happy coding..

Comment: Sorry but i cant.  I'm new here,  and voting up require 15 reputation. But thanks.